# Как узнать возможные значения параметров классификатора в scikit-learn из Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

Например, мы создали классификатор:

```
from sklearn import linear_model  
classifier = linear_model.SGDClassifier()
```

Теперь мы можем узнать параметры через:

```
classifier.get_params().keys()
```

Параметр `loss`, например, может принимать значения `hinge`, `log` и другие.

Как узнать эти возможные значения из Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Jupyter / iPython можно вызвать функцию / метод / конструктор класса со знаком вопроса, чтобы получить соответствующий `Docstring`.

---

Пример:

```
In [22]: linear_model.SGDClassifier?
Init signature:
linear_model.SGDClassifier(
    loss='hinge',
    penalty='l2',
    alpha=0.0001,
    l1_ratio=0.15,
    fit_intercept=True,
    max_iter=1000,
    tol=0.001,
    shuffle=True,
    verbose=0,
    epsilon=0.1,
    n_jobs=None,
    random_state=None,
    learning_rate='optimal',
    eta0=0.0,
    power_t=0.5,
    early_stopping=False,
    validation_fraction=0.1,
    n_iter_no_change=5,
    class_weight=None,
    warm_start=False,
    average=False,
)
```

> ```
> Docstring:
> Linear classifiers (SVM, logistic regression, a.o.) with SGD training.
>
> ...
>
> Read more in the :ref:`User Guide <sgd>`.
>
> Parameters
> ----------
> loss : str, default: 'hinge'
>     The loss function to be used. Defaults to 'hinge', which gives a
>     linear SVM.
>
>     The possible options are 'hinge', 'log', 'modified_huber',
>     'squared_hinge', 'perceptron', or a regression loss: 'squared_loss',
>     'huber', 'epsilon_insensitive', or 'squared_epsilon_insensitive'.
>
>     The 'log' loss gives logistic regression, a probabilistic classifier.
>     'modified_huber' is another smooth loss that brings tolerance to
>     outliers as well as probability estimates.
>     'squared_hinge' is like hinge but is quadratically penalized.
>     'perceptron' is the linear loss used by the perceptron algorithm.
>     The other losses are designed for regression but can be useful in
>     classification as well; see SGDRegressor for a description.
> ...
> ```